# How can I change margins of mdframed boxes that enclose ExSheets questions?

Tags: mdframed, exsheets

I successfully enclosed my *ExSheets* questions with *mdframed* boxes by using the following code line:

```
\SetupExSheets{question/pre-body-hook=\mdframed,question/post-body-hook=\endmdframed}
```

Now, I would like to add the options below:

```
innermargin =+1cm
outermargin =+1cm
```

But I don't know how. I'm aware of

```
\begin{mdframed}[innermargin=+1cm,outermargin=+1cm]
   \lipsum[2]
\end{mdframed}
```

but replacing `\mdframed` with `\begin{mdframed}` and `\endmdframed` with `\end{mdframed}` to have

```
\SetupExSheets{%
  question/pre-body-hook={\begin{mdframed}[innermargin=+1cm,outermargin=+1cm]},
  question/post-body-hook={\end{mdframed}}
}
```

doesn't work.

---

Edition: code added. What I want is to change width of the lipsum[2] and the box without changing width of lipsum[1] and lipsum[3] parts:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\exercisespace}
\newenvironment{exercicioComEspaco}[1][0pt]
  {\setlength{\exercisespace}{#1}\question}
  {\endquestion
   \ifdim\exercisespace>0pt
     \mdframed\vspace{\exercisespace}\endmdframed
   \fi}

\begin{document}

  \lipsum[1]

  \begin{exercicioComEspaco}[3cm]
     \lipsum[2]
  \end{exercicioComEspaco}

   \lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: An example document is needed.

Comment: @egreg You can use the same minimal working example you gave me as the solution to this other question:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282769/how-to-expand-exsheets-question-environment-to-show-user-defined-blank-space-for
Just show me how to change the width of the question text and of the blank box (without changing the width of the text surrounding the question if there is some).

Comment: Please, add the code nonetheless.

Comment: Naturally, I would like a solution that change this width for all document questions at once.

Comment: OK. Minimal working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your attempt missed the braces, so the comma confused the parser.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetupExSheets{
  question/pre-body-hook={\mdframed[innermargin=+1cm,outermargin=+1cm]},
  question/post-body-hook=\endmdframed
}

\newlength{\exercisespace}
\newenvironment{exercicioComEspaco}[1][0pt]
  {\setlength{\exercisespace}{#1}\question}
  {\endquestion
   \ifdim\exercisespace>0pt
     \mdframed\vspace{\exercisespace}\endmdframed
   \fi}

\begin{document}

  \lipsum[1]

  \begin{exercicioComEspaco}[3cm]
     \lipsum[2]
  \end{exercicioComEspaco}

   \lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to apply the width of the exercise text to the blank box too. I would also like to erase the line enclosing the exercise text (but don't know how to set the margins without mdframed). Naturally, the line enclosing the blank box should remain, otherwise all of this would have been in vain. Probably I'll get this by setting some "border line thickness" variable to zero and adjusting "\setwidth" in the environment definition... I have to go out now but I'm going to try it when I'm back.