# How to expand ExSheets question environment to show user-defined blank space for solution?

Tags: environments, exsheets

This is my minimal not-working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\newenvironment{exerciseWithSpace}[1]{\begin{question}}{\end{question} \mdframed \vspace{#1} \endmdframed }

\begin{document}

  \begin{exerciseWithSpace}[3cm]
     Bla bla bla.
  \end{exercicioWithSpace}

\end{document}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \endexerciseWithSpace.
```

Doubling `#` in `#1` causes another error:

```
LaTeX Error: \begin{question} on input line 10 ended by \end{exe rciseWithSpace}.
```

This is the new environment I try to create, so I guess I still don't get how to create them right.

Comment: You're trying to access the parameter `#1` in the end code of an environment defined with `\newenvironment`. That does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors in your code:

1. you can't use `#1` in the “end part” of the environment's definition;
2. you define the argument as mandatory but use it as an optional one;
3. `\begin{question}` and `\end{question}` should be `\question` and `\endquestion`, because of how this environment is defined by `exsheets`.

Since the environment is `exerciseWithSpace`, the argument seems mandatory, so

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\newlength{\exercisespace}
\newenvironment{exerciseWithSpace}[1]
  {\setlength{\exercisespace}{#1}\question}
  {\endquestion\mdframed\vspace{\exercisespace}\endmdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{exerciseWithSpace}{3cm}
Bla bla bla.
\end{exerciseWithSpace}

\end{document}
```

Instead of passing the explicit argument in `\vspace`, we save it in a register.

[image]

You might want a generic `exercise` environment, with an optional argument that, if present, would trigger leaving the required space.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\newlength{\exercisespace}
\newenvironment{exercise}[1][0pt]
  {\setlength{\exercisespace}{#1}\question}
  {\endquestion
   \ifdim\exercisespace>0pt
     \mdframed\vspace{\exercisespace}\endmdframed
   \fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[3cm]
Bla bla bla.
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same (note the square brackets, though). With

```
\begin{exercise}
Bla bla bla.
\end{exercise}
```

you'd get no box.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to choose your solution because it's closer to what I already have and doesn't require importing a new package.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with `exsheets` really, but the problem isn't really related to `exsheets` but to the fact that `#1` isn't possible in the end code of an environment defined with the traditional `\newenvironment` command.

It's possible with `\NewDocumentEnvironment` from `xparse` package (shown here) or with `\NewEnviron`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{exerciseWithSpace}{oD<>{3cm}}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \question{#1}%
  }{%
    \question%
  } 
}{%
  \endquestion% 
  \begin{mdframed} 
    \vspace{#2} 
  \end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exerciseWithSpace}[8]<5cm>
  Bla bla bla.
\end{exerciseWithSpace}


\begin{exerciseWithSpace}<3cm>
  Bla bla bla.
\end{exerciseWithSpace}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you! Nice to know about those other commands.